# Creating Ethernet II frame header?

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel, raw-ethernet

How to create `Ethernet II` frame header in Linux ?  802.3 frame header can be created using `eth_header()` giving the `skbuffer` and source and destination MAC and length. Can the same function be used for `Ethernet II` frame format also, where we use type field instead of length?

Answer (score 1):

The (current) kernel sources define the method in question the following way:

```
int eth_header(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev,
           unsigned short type,
           const void *daddr, const void *saddr, unsigned len);
```

So we *do* have a `type` field. So far so good.

Let's look at the method's implementation, whether and how the value of `type` is taken into account. The method starts like this:

```
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = ...

    if (type != ETH_P_802_3 && type != ETH_P_802_2)
            eth->h_proto = htons(type);
    else
            eth->h_proto = htons(len);
    ...
```

As we can see, *for all types but 802.2/3 the value of `type` (passed to the function) is used to initialise the frame header*, which is what we want for Ethernet II frame headers.

Conclusion and answer to the question: **Yes**, one can use `eth_header()` to create an Ethernet II frame header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let us say for example i have a type field of 8100(vlan tagging) so when i call this function i should pass ETH_P_802_2 to type filed and 8100 to len field .Is that correct?

Comment: @user1023527: Actullay this could work (at leasth using the currrent sources) ... - but I'd recommend to pass `ETH_P_8021Q` (from  `/usr/src/linux/include/linux/if_ether.h`) via `type` and pass nothing (`0`) via `len`.

Comment: @user1023527: *"VLAN tagging*" is 802.1Q (`ETH_P_8021Q`) and `ETH_P_8021Q` in turn is `#define`ed to be `8100`.

Answer (score 0):

Cf. `net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6t_REJECT.c` and `net/ethernet/eth.c`.:

```
nskb = skb_alloc(...);
...
struct ethhdr *eh = skb_push(nskb, sizeof(struct ethhdr));
eh->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IPV6);
```

You can change the amount of bytes allocated and/or pushed depending on what you want to add to the packet.